# What input operator can we use in C that ignores 'space' and accepts 'Enter' while taking array inputs

Tags: c, arrays

Consider an example:

```
5
1 0 5
1 1 7
1 0 3
2 1 0
2 1 1
```

Here, in the first line, 5 denotes the size of the array.
I'm entering five sequences one by one.
I want the first sequence ie. 1 0 5 to be stored in `arr[0]`.

Note: 1, 0 and 5 are seperated by spaces.
However, `arr[0]` should contain 105 without any space.

I want to accept the next sequence into arr[1] only after pressing 'Enter'.
So that `arr[1]` should contain 117, `arr[2]` should contain 103 and so on up to `arr[4]`.

Is there any operator that I can use for this?

Comment: There is no operator, You will have to write a program to do this.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text but post the text. Is this so difficult ?

Comment: _There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs._

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Answer (score 3):

There are no operators that do I/O in C at all, so no.

I also don't think there's any standard *function* with those semantics, they tend to view all whitespace as equal.

You should write your own, probably using `fgets()` to read in whole lines and then extracting the digits to convert to integers.